# iOS Reduce the payload size while publishing data on MQTT protocol

Tags: arrays, swift, aws-iot, payload

I am working with accelerometer and gyroscope data, I need to publish 50Hz (50 records in a second) data via MQTT protocol, There is 30 seconds buffer at mobile end which collects are data and then we need to publish that data via MQTT protocol.
I am facing MQTT disconnection because of large amount of data. If we capture 30 second data the data size becomes 0.3 MB. which is not possible to publish. I can't use any kind of compression.
Can someone suggest how we can publish large amount of data or how we can reduce the payload size to 20KB max ?
I am using `AWSIoT` & `AWSMobileClient` for MQTT connection.

In one second accelerometer gives 50 records, so in 30 seconds 50 * 30 = 1500 dictionaries created and same for the gyroscope is happening.

Data format:

```
{
  "data": {
    "accelerometerData": [
      {
        "timeStamp": 1661747241,
        "xAxis": 1231233.123231,
        "yAxis": 1231233.123231,
        "zAxis": 1231233.123231
      },
      {
        "timeStamp": 1661747241,
        "xAxis": 1231233.123231,
        "yAxis": 1231233.123231,
        "zAxis": 1231233.123231
      },
      {
        "timeStamp": 1661747241,
        "xAxis": 1231233.123231,
        "yAxis": 1231233.123231,
        "zAxis": 1231233.123231
      },
      {
        "timeStamp": 1661747241,
        "xAxis": 1231233.123231,
        "yAxis": 1231233.123231,
        "zAxis": 1231233.123231
      }
    ],
    "gyroscopeData": [
        {
          "timeStamp": 1661747241,
          "xAxis": 1231233.123231,
          "yAxis": 1231233.123231,
          "zAxis": 1231233.123231
        },
        {
          "timeStamp": 1661747241,
          "xAxis": 1231233.123231,
          "yAxis": 1231233.123231,
          "zAxis": 1231233.123231
        },
        {
          "timeStamp": 1661747241,
          "xAxis": 1231233.123231,
          "yAxis": 1231233.123231,
          "zAxis": 1231233.123231
        },
        {
          "timeStamp": 1661747241,
          "xAxis": 1231233.123231,
          "yAxis": 1231233.123231,
          "zAxis": 1231233.123231
        }
    ]
  },
  "userid": "logged_in_user_id",
  "deviceid": "deviceid//",
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Late answer for everyone who arrives by google:

A page in the AWS IoT documentation called [AWS IoT Core message broker and protocol limits and quotas](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/iot-core.html#message-broker-limits) states that the maximum size per publish is 128 KB and the maximum throughput is 512 KB per connection per second. The maximum amount of publishes is 100/sec.

If you cannot use compression then the obvious solution here is to buffer 10 seconds of data (100 KB) and send it every 10 seconds instead of every 30 seconds. Or to go for every 5 seconds (50KB) if you want to play it safe.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to go above the aws iot cote throughput, then maybe look at other services like AWS Kinesis. Mqtt is good for telemetry, not data streaming.

I’m not sure how you are connecting to aws iot core. If you use x509 certificates then you can make a call to aws iot credential provider to retrieve temporary credentials and then use them to make https call to kinesis.

I believe aws iot core is just a way to enter into aws cloud, your data will end up in a datalake or timestream. Kinesis can integrates with both.

Answer (score 0):

Why not sending two arrays without attribute names ?

gyroscope: [timestamp,x1,y1,z1,timestamp2,x2,y2,z2,…]

This should reduce the size of the payload.

Then, do you need all the data or can you send deltas ? So you can skip timestamp where it did not move.